# Typo3: ImageMagick combine does not work

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, typo3

I'm looking to use image masks in Typo3. After trying out various things and none of them worked, I decided to check out the install tool.

Install tool says ImageMagick is installed correctly, paths are correct and all image test complete successfully, **except the convert/combine test**. The test says "There was no result from the ImageMagick operation".

Also, when I'm using gifbuilder to output an image the image's dimensions get read correctly, allthough the outputted image stays blank. (which is white or another color when I have backColor set)

I am using:

- Max OSX 10.7.5
- XAMPP
- PHP 5.3.1
- Typo3 6.0.4
- ImageMagic 6.7.3-2

Here is some test typoscript code (which on my install results in a fully red image instead of the original image)

```
lib.test = IMAGE
lib.test {
    file = GIFBUILDER
    file {
        XY = [10.w],[10.h]
        backColor = #FF0000

        10 = IMAGE
        10.file = fileadmin/user_upload/test.jpg
    }
}
```

Attached is the result from the `combining images test`.

[image]

**Does anyone have an idea as to what I might be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some newer imagemagick versions use `composite` as command instead of `combine`. There is an option in the install tool to set the command to use. The setting is called `[GFX][im_combine_filename]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Setting `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['im_combine_filename'] = 'composite';` has solved the issue in the install tool. My code still doesn't work though lol. Do you have an idea what it might be?

Comment: Nope, I don't use GIFBUILDER very often... One other thing: you should consider upgrading to PHP 5.3.7 at least, before that version a PHP bug could cause problems (but only with extensions, as far as I understand it).